# What determines noise spectral density of diode-resistors?

Tags: resistors, diodes, noise, noise-spectral-density

One common way to think of a diode is that it is a variable resistor, whose resistance depends on its voltage drop and can be controlled via its bias current.

I have two questions about how far this analogy holds with respect to a practical circuit.

1. In the below circuit one can tune the resistance of the diode via its bias current I1 and, as a result, change the time constant of the "RC" lowpass formed by D1 and C1. Does this indeed work ? CircuitLab and LTspice agree that this works and it sounds like a versatile tool.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQRfGCm.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

2. In the same circuit if the voltage source is considered noisefree, the output noise spectral density of an RC circuit will be flat given by the resistor thermal noise and eventually drop at 20 dB/dec beyond the corner frequency of the RC lowpass. We know from (1) above that the corner frequency can be tuned via I1. **But what determines the white noise of the diode ?** LTspice seems to suggest that a diode-resistor has in fact the same noise (at the same cutoff frequency) compared to the corresponding resistor. Are there some additional noise contributions that the sim does not capture here, given that diodes are not really simple resistors ?(See below)

Regular resistor noise:

[image]

Diode-resistor noise:

[image]

As suggested by Neil_UK, here is a comparison of the Johnson current noise and Shot current noise of a forward biased diode. The Johnson contribution is calculated using the equivalent resistance of the diode via the Shockley equation. They are of similar magnitude for an ideal diode, but for all practical resistances, the Shot noise actually dominates. So when current noise density is important, it looks like the diode-resistors are worse than resistors (1/f noise isn't considered both).

[image]

As this Shot noise current has to flow through the effective resistance of the diode, it should also cause a noise voltage drop across the diode. So by the same logic, the shot noise would also cause a moderate increase in voltage noise in a diode vs a passive resistor, correct?

[image]

Comment: diodes exhibit shot noise as well as johnson noise

Comment: @Neil_UK is there some estimation for that similar to the \$\sqrt{4 k_B T R}\$ for resistors ? I found  \$\sqrt{2 e I}\$ in wiki, but does that mean that shot noise is purely a current noise ?

Comment: Yes, purely a current noise! More current, more noise absolutely, but better SNR if the current is the signal. Of course the noise is generated by any bias current as well, so keeping bias small if the signal is small is important for SNR. Hence the 140 uA typical bias current of the classic RIAA phono BJT input stage (if you're old enough to have met those designs).

Comment: @Neil_UK thanks. So that would mean that diodes are decent/equivalent in terms of noise as long as the current is small (the emulated resistor is large) but not so good to replace lower valued resistors because the shot noise would overshadow the Johnson noise ?

Comment: Using a diode to emulate a resistance works, if you want a constant resistance, over only a very tiny range, so your signal is automatically much less than your bias current, which is bad for SNR. I've not used diodes in low noise applications, so haven't the rules of thumb to hand, but with those formulae, it would take you second to rustle up a spreadsheet. Post it once you've done it.

Comment: Not sure how LTSpice incorporates noise in its models, or how you turn them on and off. The archetypal circuit using current through a diode junction (of a transistor) to control resistance is in the [Moog Current Controlled Ladder Filter](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/technical-articles/analyzing-the-moog-filter/)

Comment: @Neil_UK I have added the charts you suggested, it looks like the shot noise is almost always important and slightly larger than the Johnson noise. The noise increase vs a pure resistor is a factor of 2-3 typically. For very low bias, the shot noise is so low, that the diode becomes pretty close to a passive resistor, but this is already in the >GOhm range, where other things matter.