# Why does the RC corner frequency change when replacing the resistor with an equivalent diode?

Tags: resistors, diodes, low-pass

This is slightly related to [another question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/589785/do-diodes-have-lower-johnson-noise-than-corresponding-resistors?noredirect=1) but actually a matter of its own:

This is a simple analysis of the corner frequency of an RC lowpass formed by resistor R1 and capacitor C1, for various values of R1:

[image]

Now when replacing the resistor with a diode with the same equivalent resistance, the behavior changes. It appears as if the effective resistance of the diode is more than 10x lower, than its actual instantaneous resistance. The nominal resistance of the diode set by current I1 has the same value as the resistor above.

[image]

**So the question is**, why does the diode circuit behave differently than the resistor circuit ? I confirmed that the currents and voltage drops are nearly the same in both cases, so the effective resistance of the diode is indeed very close to the nominal resistance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your choice of bias current = \$0.6 V / R\$ provides for the same large-signal equivalent resistance \$V/I\$, but it does not provide for the same *small-signal* resistance (\$dV/dI\$).

This is an important distinction because your AC analysis specifically uses these small-signal resistances in its linearized model -- the result of the AC analysis is specifically intended to answer the question "what is the small-signal AC behavior of the circuit, for a small-signal AC input superimposed on its DC operating point?"

Further, in the case of the noise analysis in your linked question, this small-signal resistance is precisely the one that a small noise voltage "sees" when superimposed upon the operating point.

In this case, the diode current is given approximately by \$I = I_0e^{V/V_T}\$; differentiating it with respect to voltage yields a \$dI/dV\$ of \$\frac{I_0e^{V/V_T}}{V_T} = \frac{I}{V_T}\$, or a \$dV/dI\$ of \$\frac{V_T}{I}\$. This is much smaller than \$V/I\$ when the diode is turned on.

You can compare these graphically:

[image: plot of diode I/V characteristic with secant and tangent lines drawn]

The blue line's slope is the large-signal impedance you calculated. The red line's slope is the small-signal impedance that's relevant to AC analysis.

Comment: Makes perfect sense. Thanks a lot!